# 'rollup' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, command-line-interface, rollup

I would like to ask if how should I fix this issue because I am already stuck and confused about this part. I already installed rollup globally using this command

```
npm install --global rollup
```

However when I tried to run the 'rollup' command then I should expect the rollup information or something will show in my CLI? but my CLI shows

> 'rollup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What I have done so far is.

1. Updated the NPM
2. Reinstall the rollup globally.

I already read some documentation but the issue is still showing.https://github.com/Esri/ago-assistant/issues/176

Please enlighten me.
Thank you

Comment: interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://github.com/Esri/ago-assistant/issues/176

Comment: Thanks, @jsocaI, already tried it but the issue is still there on my end. I don't know how they fixed the issue? because they already close the issue.

Comment: I just got this error because I forgot the `npm install` command in my corresponding folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I just have done just to run the script globally.

I just added these scripts in my package.json to run the rollup using NPM.

```
 "scripts": {
"rollup": "rollup"
```

is this okay?

Answer (score 4):

```
npm install
```

fixed this issue for me

Comment: easy solution for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Try restarting your terminal
2. Try locating where the Rollup binary is installed
   **%AppData%\npm\node_modules** or  **%AppData%\roaming\npm\node_modules**
   and run it manually like

   %AppData%\npm\node_modules\rollup\bin\rollup.exe

Comment: Hi @E.Eldridge,I just want to ask if I should have this file rollup.exe in the rollup directory? because upon checking, I haven't see rollup.exe in the rollup directory?

Comment: @CarlDaveTampoy It may not have the .exe extension, is there anything that you can execute in that folder? It may just be called **rollup**.

Comment: @E.Elridge , my node_modules in a rollup directory is empty but in the dist folder there is rollup.browser.js rollup.d.ts and rollup.js.

Comment: @CarlDaveTampoy Look in the **bin** folder next to those files. You should be able to run `node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup`. If that doesn't work then delete your **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** and re-run `npm install`