# npm start/npm run dev not working for react and svelte

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svelte

I’m new to JS frameworks and I created a svelte project which was working fine until I opened it again today and “npm run dev” isn’t working anymore. Even in my react apps, “npm start” shows same error. For svelte it shows “sh: rollup: command not found. Even when I create a new react/svelte app it still shows the same error. Please help I have no idea what to do anymore. This is my package.json file for the svelte app.. I have also tried uninstalling my node version and updating to the latest. still same error

```json
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear --port 8080"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide more context information about your problem. @Moses Chukwudi Nwigberi

Comment: The issue mostly is in your package.json file, check your script, or share the content of the package.json

Comment: @BoshraJaber I have added the package.json file

Comment: @Dolphin I have added more context

Comment: @MosesChukwudiNwigberi I don't think this error is related to node. Also, the package.json file is all good. Try `npm install` again, maybe it will fix the issue

Comment: @BoshraJaber tried that too, didn't work sadly ;-(

Comment: did this fixed your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400015/rollup-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command @MosesChukwudiNwigberi